# Sync Bitbucket server repository with another repository

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

I had a repository hosted on bitbucket cloud which I copied to bitbucket server instance using 
https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/importing-code-from-an-existing-project-776640909.html

I used "**Import an existing Git project into Bitbucket Server**" method in the above URL.

Now, there are some updates made on the cloud repository (new branches, commits etc.) which I want to move to my Bitbucket server repository. How can I do that ?

One method I can think of is:
- clone bitbucket server repository
- add bitbucket cloud repo as new remote
- pull changes from bitbucket cloud repo
- push changes to bitbucket server repo

But the problem with above method is while pulling changes from bitbucket cloud repo, I don't know which branches to pull. I want all branches and commits to be synced.

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: maybe this helps:
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056327/how-do-i-synchronise-two-remote-git-repositories](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15056327/how-do-i-synchronise-two-remote-git-repositories)

Answer (score 2):

You might try one of the [mirroring/sync related add-ons](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/search?q=mirror%20repository) available on the Atlassian Marketplace. A couple of them are for outbound mirroring (pushing changes *to* a remote). I do know that ScriptRunner supports inbound mirroring.

Alternatively, as you describe you could externally manage syncing by having a clone with 2 remotes where you pull all changes from the cloud host and push them to the Bitbucket Server instance, and that could then be automated on a schedule or trigger.